Wait a minute, this *is* 1 across!

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Woman in white dress gets good partner that's worth marrying, as he can let 1 across? (12)
9. Big name in French cinema, Jean, with one Oscar, ultimately (6)
11. East Asian ruler liable to vacate punishment (5)
13. Free source (6)
15. On part I, if part II starts from Q? (4)
17. Essentials of deluxe restaurant party (4)
18. Perfect specimen gains acceptance as symbol (5)
19. Two men in ring terrorised tailless mouse (4)
21. The woman's drinking beer – one can give life to a party? (6)
24. Wash hair in separate section (5)
25. Regina ditches exceptionally strong tool (5)
27. General's order not apt (6)
28. Running out after first sign of armoured vehicle (4)
30. African States tracking extreme elements in Havana (5)
32. "King" associated with Asian people (4)
34. I must refrain from wordless diplomacy (4)
36. Unlimited Tibet Air – revolutionary airline (6)
38. 71% of earnings get returned... when pigs fly (5)
39. Swiss scientists protecting foremost of academics against underground network (6)
40. Promising support being given to Paraguayan NGO, for the most part (12)
Down
1. The rat involved in making bread? That's magnificent! (12)
2. Schoolmaster scratches right side (5)
3. Copy of car with twice the power resulting, in the end, in safety risk (12)
4. Back up father's Discord server? (4)
5. Unendingly respectful family (3)
6. Pat and Olive struggled with exit having tendency towards unfair treatment (12)
7. Hole in one secured by PGA Tour beginners (3)
8. Group in Turin housed in great inn – surprisingly refreshing! (12)
10. India broke away to become a republic (4)
12. Conducts heavy metal symphony's opening (5)
14. Where to find iron: In my golf set up (3)
16. Clothe topless kid (4)
20. Army member is not avoiding me (3)
22. Numerous men escaped, or at least one (3)
23. For the hearing, court orders excessively showy display (4)
26. Church coated in mined substance that's yellowish-orange (5)
29. IDF staple tending to seep through the grapevine (3)
30. Wife of serial adulterer is in therapy (4)
31. Disregard number under twenty almost completely (5)
33. Group centred around charismatic leader? (4)
35. Green in Hollywood? Green car seen near southern part of LA (3)
37. Mount Franklin (3)

Grid:

 

Across

 1. Woman in white dress gets good partner that's worth marrying, as he can let 1 across? (12)
BRIDGEKEEPER (he can let one across) = BRIDE gets G + KEEPER

 9. Big name in French cinema, Jean, with one Oscar, ultimately (6)
 Jean RENOIR &lit: Jean RENO with I (osca)R

 11. East Asian ruler liable to vacate punishment (5)
EXILE (punishment) = E + XI Jin Ping + L(iabl)E (vacating itself, I guess)

 13. Free source (6)
SPRING ddef (free as a verb)

 15. On part I, if part II starts from Q? (4)
ATOP (on): Since part II starts from Q then part I would be A TO P

 17. Essentials of deluxe restaurant party (4)
LUAU or lūʻau (party) = (de)LU(xe) (rest)AU(rant)

 18. Perfect specimen gains acceptance as symbol (5)
TOKEN (symbol) = TEN (perfect specimen, i.e. one so excellent that it deserves a perfect rating) gains OK

 19. Two men in ring terrorised tailless mouse (4)
SUMO (two men in ring) = MOUS(-e)*

 21. The woman's drinking beer – one can give life to a party? (6)
HEALER (one can give life to a party, in roleplaying/online games) = HER drinking ALE

 24. Wash hair in separate section (5)
RINSE hidden word

 25. Regina ditches exceptionally strong tool (5)
TONGS = ST(-r)ONG*

 27. General's order not apt (6)
 George S. PATTON Jr. = NOTAPT* (order as a verb)

 28. Running out after first sign of armoured vehicle (4)
AUTO (vehicle) = OUT* after A(rmoured)

 30. African States tracking extreme elements in Havana (5)
HAUSA (African people spread across West Africa) = USA tracking H(avan)A

 32. "King" associated with Asian people (4)
KHAN &lit: K + HAN Chinese

 34. I must refrain from wordless diplomacy (4)
TACT (diplomacy) = TAC(-i)T

 36. Unlimited Tibet Air – revolutionary airline (6)
IBERIA (airline) = (-t)IBE(-t) + AIR<

 38. 71% of earnings get returned... when pigs fly (5)
NEVER (when pigs fly; i.e. they can't at all!) = REVEN(-ue)< (5/7 ≈ 71%)

 39. Swiss scientists protecting foremost of academics against underground network (6)
CAVERN (underground network) = CERN protecting A(cademics) + V (against, versus)

 40. Promising support being given to Paraguayan NGO, for the most part (12)
GUARANTEEING (promising) = TEE (support for a sports ball) being given to GUARANI (a kind of Paraguayan) NG(-o)

Down

 1. The rat involved in making bread? That's magnificent! (12)
BREATHTAKING (magnificent) = THERAT* in BAKING

 2. Schoolmaster scratches right side (5)
RECTO (side, in general the front side of a flat object) = RECTO(-r)

 3. Copy of car with twice the power resulting, in the end, in safety risk (12)
DOPPELGANGER (copy) = OP(+P)EL (OPEL car with twice the P) + (resultin)G in DANGER

 4. Back up father's Discord server? (4)
ERIS (Discord server, i.e. one who serves discord) = SIRE<

 5. Unendingly respectful family (3)
KIN (family) = KIN(-d)

 6. Pat and Olive struggled with exit having tendency towards unfair treatment (12)
EXPLOITATIVE (having tendency towards unfair treatment) = (PAT OLIVE EXIT)*

 7. Hole in one secured by PGA Tour beginners (3)
PIT (hole) = I secured by P(ga) T(our)

 8. Group in Turin housed in great inn – surprisingly refreshing! (12)
REJUVENATING (refreshing) = JUVE (alias of Juventus FC, a soccer group based in Turin) housed in GREATINN*

 10. India broke away to become a republic (4)
IRAN (republic) = I + RAN

 12. Conducts heavy metal symphony's opening (5)
LEADS (conducts) = LEAD + S(ymphony)

 14. Where to find iron: In my golf set up (3)
GYM (where to find iron weights) = (MY G)<

 16. Clothe topless kid (4)
QUIP (kid, i.e. to banter) = (-e)QUIP

 20. Army member is not avoiding me (3)
ANT (army member) = A(-i)N'T

 22. Numerous men escaped, or at least one (3)
ANY (at least one, e.g. "Do you have any food?") = (-m)ANY

 23. For the hearing, court orders excessively showy display (4)
RITZ (excessively showy display) = WRITS homophone

 26. Church coated in mined substance that's yellowish-orange (5)
OCHRE (yellowish-orange) = CH coated in ORE

 29. IDF staple tending to seep through the grapevine (3)
UZI (IDF staple, i.e. the gun they mainly use) = OOZY (tending to seep) homophone (to hear "through the grapevine" means to hear through rumors, indeed implying hearing)

 30. Wife of serial adulterer is in therapy (4)
HERA (wife of serial adulterer Zeus) hidden word

 31. Disregard number under twenty almost completely (5)
SCORN (disregard) = N under SCOR(-e)

 33. Group centred around charismatic leader? (4)
SECT &lit: SET centred around C(harismatic)

 35. Green in Hollywood? Green car seen near southern part of LA (3)
 Eva GREEN (Green in Hollywood) = EV (green car, electric vehicle) seen near (-l)A

 37. Mount Franklin (3)
BEN ddef: Scottish/Irish mountain, and Benjamin Franklin

